# Capital Casing in metro apps

Tags: xaml

I'm using a textbox which should automatically convert lower case letters into upper case. I tried searching for **CharacterCasing** but that property wasn't available.I've tried using TextInput event handler. I wanted to know is there any other property that'll allow me to change lower case to upper case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property in WinRT TextBox : [List of WinRT TextBox properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209683#properties)

Solution : listen to `TextChanged` event and convert text to upper in event handler method (example implementation can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/09276ef6-556a-4fb7-9d1b-181cf84db304/windows-8-winrt-textbox-upper-case-setting)), or use converter along with data binding if you are following MVVM pattern.